# Create azure bearer token from azure function

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

How can I create azure bearer authorization token from inside azure functions to run , azure run commands inside an azure VM by rest API? The documentations are not helping

Comment: Please include more details in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very easy to get an access token, here is an example of httpTrigger function for your reference:

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
#r "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory"

using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;

public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    string AadInstance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}";
    string ResourceId = "https://management.azure.com/";
    AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(string.Format(AadInstance, "{tenant}"));
    authenticationContext.ExtendedLifeTimeEnabled = true;
    ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential("{clientId}", "{clientSecret}");
    AuthenticationResult authticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(ResourceId, clientCredential).Result;
    string token=authticationResult.AccessToken;

    return (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"bearer token is: {token}");
}
```

If you don't know how to get the clientId and clientSecret, you can follow this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/#register-your-client-application-with-azure-ad) to register the application on Azure portal.